# What do these three things have in common?

Tags: word

What do these three things have in commmon?

> A sandwich shop, a computer and a casino.
>   
> <sub>— from [The Puzzling World of Winston Breen](https://books.google.com/books?id=z8xczEDByaIC)</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Note in the future that you can wait a few hours before accepting an answer, so that the puzzle gets more attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be

> they all have chips? A sandwich shop has a chip card reader (and potato chips, thanks @deep thought), a computer has computer chips, and a casino has poker chips.

Comment: Or the edible kind

Comment: @deepthought Haha, that should've been more obvious, I guess I live in the tech age... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but how about:

> Virus - spoiled food (i.e. potentially romaine lettuce in the US in Nov. and Dec.), a computer virus (malware, Trojan, etc.), the "Lady-of-the-Night" sorta virus (well, you know ;-P)

Answer (score 1):

Also, they all have or are

> **wafers**. For example, a sandwich shop with a sufficiently wide repertoire would carry cookie sandwiches, which [include wafers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cookie_sandwiches). Many computer components are built on [wafers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wafer_(electronics)). And then there are [Casino wafers](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-u-fXW0XTDso/Wc8MEZddXqI/AAAAAAAAp2w/v5trIhccRw0hpDi0wys5RXvmRtn6vhkBQCLcBGAs/s1600/Casino.JPG).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> The letter **C** (works with **O** too).
>
>  A sandwi**c**h shop, a **c**omputer and a **c**asino.